# Eclipse formatter doesn't let me change my brackets conventions

Tags: eclipse, brackets, formatter, curly-braces

I have one really simple problem: when I write blocks of codes, eg:

```
do{
}
```

I would like eclipse to do

```
do
{
}
```

I went into my Formatter, changed every single line to "Next line", made a new profile, I did select it, apply, save, apply and close. So everything is setted correctly.

But nothing have changed, I still get the result that I do not want when typing do{+space

Answer (score 0):

You can apply Formatter settings from the `Source` menu or with the <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+F</kbd> shortcut (on Windows).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have found a **bug**:

With your formatter settings and if in *Window > **Preferences: Java > Editor > Typing***, in section ***Automatically insert at correct position*** the checkbox ***Braces*** is checked, the position of `{` should be corrected as you type. But the result is

```
do {
```

instead of

```
do
{
```

[Could you please report it to Eclipse.](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=JDT)